# Recording multi fx unit directly to a computer

Tags: recording

I have a Zoom G1on multi effects unit and it had a stereo 1/4 jack output. Is it possible to record from the fx unit straight to a mic input of a macbook, using to 1/4 to 1/8 jack converter? There is an option on the Amp sim of the multifx to set the output to line out. The fx unit does not have a usb interface.

Comment: Which specific Macbook model?

You'll definitely want to use a line-in port instead of mic, but some Macs have combination mic/line ports.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on which model of the MacBook you have.

The Retina models lack line-in, but if you have an older version, you have to set your input to "Line-in" instead of "built-in microphone" and you're ready to go.

But, the combo-port has the iPhone head-set support (full, with remote control and microphone), so it must have *some* form of audio input, but I haven't tested it.